# Exact site image using WAMP and URIs

Tags: windows, apache, server

Is it possible to replicate locally a web site using something like "example.local" for the domain instead of "example.com", using the WAMP server application in Win7?

I know this question has been posted several times, but what I want is to create local sites in a single directory different from WAMP or Windows directories, that can be accessed using an URI format. Example http://example.local instead of http://example.com.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

Lets say your site is located under "public_html" directory at the remote server.

Usually local sites are created in the WAMP server "www" directory at Windows partition, but you can create them in any other partition when available.

You want to place all your local sites in partition E:, for example.

1. Create a local sites directory in partition E. i.e. "Sites"
   (E:\Sites).
2. Create your first local site directory under "Sites". i.e.
   "MyFirstSite" (E:\Sites\MyFirstSite)
3. Define your local virtual domain for your first site. i.e
   "example.loc". Could be stackoverflow.loc or google.loc, for
   example. Use always a non-valid TLD (top-level domain) such as "LOC"
   or "LOCAL".
4. Open
   "WampDirectory\bin\apache\apacheX.X.XX\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf",
   where "WampDirectory" is the directory where you installed the WAMP
   server application and "apacheX.X.XX" is the Apache version in use.
5. Insert a block similar to this one at the bottom of
   "httpd-vhosts.conf":

   ```
       <VirtualHost *:80>
           ServerName example.loc
           ServerAlias www.example.loc  *.example.loc
           DocumentRoot "E:\Sites\MyFirstSite"
           <Directory "E:/Sites/MyFirstSite/">
               AllowOverride All
               Require local
           </Directory>
       </VirtualHost>
   ```
6. Open WinDirectory\System32\drivers\etc\hosts  (File without extension:
   "hosts")
7. Insert next lines at the bottom of the file:

   ```
       127.0.0.1 localhost
       ::1 localhost
       127.0.0.1 example.loc
       127.0.0.1 www.example.loc
   ```
8. Copy the complete remote server "public_html" directory to directory
   "E:/Sites/MyFirstSite/"
9. Execute WampDirectory\wampmanager.exe

Open your browser and type "http://example.loc" in the address bar.

You should be able to browse your local site unless it requires also a database (Wordpress, for example) to do it. If so, make a remote database dump, download it and use WAMP PhpMyAdmin to create the local database, the user and to import the downloaded database dump.

Wordpress sites also require changing WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL constants. You can do it in wp-config.php. Example;

```
$SiteURL = "http://" . $_SERVER[ "HTTP_HOST" ];
if( stripos( $_SERVER[ "HTTP_HOST" ], ".loc" ) !== FALSE ) {
define( 'WP_HOME', $SiteURL ); // NO NEED to modify Options Table manually
define( 'WP_SITEURL', $SiteURL ); // NO NEED to modify Options Table manually
}
```

Repeat from step 1 for other web sites you want to replicate locally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it, but how can I edit the hosts file without extension?

Comment: Well, you can use an editor like EditPad or copy the file, rename the original just in case, add extension "txt" to the copy, edit it, save it and remove the "txt" extension. Just a couple of ideas. I am sure there are other ways to do it.

Comment: It took me some time to download the site and to understand some of the steps, but it works. Thanks a lot. Is it possible to debug the local site in PhpStorm?

Comment: Yes. To validate, in Settings > Run > Web server Debug Validation > Path to create validation script: field, always use "WampDirectory/www/" and 
in Settings > Run > Web server Debug Validation > Url to validation script: field, use 127.0.0.1.